# Transfinite recursion, collection and replacement in KP and KF

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

Kripke Platek set theory has collection instead of replacement, and it is a weakening of KP if one has replacement instead of collection. Call KP minus collection plus replacement KF for *Kripke Fraenkel*. Is KF weaker than KP in that some transfinite recursion can be done by KP which cannot be done by KF? If so, is that a difference inherited by strengthened theories as $\Sigma _{n} KP$ and $\Sigma _{n} KF$ for $n>1$?

Comment: I don't think substituting Fraenkel for Platek like that is appropriate since Platek's contribution to KP was not just the collection axiom.

Comment: "KF" has also been used occasionally elsewhere to abbreviate "Kaye-Forster".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main deficit of KF over KP is that one cannot prove that the set of formulae equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$ formula is closed under bounded quantification.  (And this persists up through the $KF_n/KP_n$ you define.)

Therefore recursions involving schemes defined by a formula of the form  $\forall u \in v \varphi$ cannot in general be effected in KF.

At the level n=1: Mathias in: ``Weak Systems of Gandy, Jensen and Devlin'', (Trends in Mathematics, Ed. Bagaria, Todorcevic, Birkhäuser Press) states that methods of Zarach should be sufficient to give an example showing that $\Delta_0$-collection cannot be substituted
by $\Delta_0$-replacement, but does not give an example (and I don't have one).

At levels > 1:   See Gitman, Johnstone, Hamkins ``What is the theory ZFC without Power Set".
(Archive for Math.Logic, 2012) where they give examples (some derived from Zarach) of failures of even low levels of $\Sigma_n$-Collection even in models of full $\Sigma_\omega$-Replacement. They observe that one can inductively define in one such model a family of bijective functions $f:\omega \longrightarrow \aleph_k$ for $k\leq n$, but not altogether for all $n<\omega$.  Thus strengthening the replacement scheme does not help.

Comment: By $\aleph_k$ here, one should understand the $\aleph_k$'s of a ground model, which have all been collapsed to $\omega$ by forcing. The old $\aleph_\omega$ becomes the new $\omega_1$, which is singular in our model, even though it satisfies ZFC- and, in particular, the axiom of choice.

Comment: I am concerned with a construction which is strongly related to your infinite time Turing machines. Are they affected?

Comment: The recursion defining the operation of ITTMs does not seem to be affected by the replacement/collection issue, since one may undertake it inside the constructible universe $L$.

Comment: I agree with Joel's comment concerning ITTM's in L. In L the Collection vis a vis Replacement concern is not an issue as there is a global wellorder of L.  @Joel: thanks for clarifying the status of the $\aleph_n$'s in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

In our paper, [V. Gitman, J. D. Hamkins, T.A. Johnstone, What is the theory ZFC without powerset?](http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/), which arose also in one of [your previous questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137282/another-question-on-collection-and-replacement-in-sigman-kp), we prove that there is a model of ZFC-powerset using only replacement and not collection (and so it satisfies your theory KF and indeed $\Sigma_n$-KF for every $n$), which has sets of reals of size $\aleph_n$ for every finite $n$, yet no set of reals of size $\aleph_\omega$, even though this model has $\aleph_\omega$ and indeed satisfies Hartog's theorem "$\forall\alpha\aleph_\alpha$ exists". Thus, in this model, which has the axiom of choice, there is no largest well-ordered set of real numbers.

One can view this as a failure of transfinite recursion. Specifically, KP proves that if 
if every set of reals is well-orderable, and for every $n$ there is a set of reals of size $\aleph_n$, then there is a set of reals of size $\aleph_\omega$. One simply collects the smaller sets, takes the union, and well-orders it. But KF and indeed $\bigcup_n\Sigma_n$-KF does not prove this, because of our model.

But perhaps you had a more specific kind or instance of recursion in mind? If so, please describe in more detail what forms of recursion you are considering.

Comment: See my comment to Phillip Welch below.